# import pyarrow.lib as _lib ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found

Tags: environment-variables, pyarrow, libstdc++, powerpc, rpath

I am trying to import a package called pyarrow. And meet a problem:

```
import pyarrow.lib as _lib

ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found(required by /usr/workspace/lei5/myenv/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/lib.cpython-38-powerpc64le-linux-gnu.so)
```

I thought this should because of the env variant. Then I use

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/workspace/lei5/myenv/pytorch/lib
```

to import the correct env variant. I checked the libstdc++.so.6 file within this /usr/workspace/lei5/myenv/pytorch/lib path by using:

```
strings /usr/workspace/lei5/myenv/pytorch/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep CXXABI
```

It does contains libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9.
And in order to make sure the env variant correctly set, I use

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

It only contains /usr/workspace/lei5/myenv/pytorch/lib.
I then run my bash file again and the error is the same.....
I also checked the RUNPATH and RPATH by using:

```
readelf -d /usr/workspace/lei5/myenv/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/lib.cpython-38-powerpc64le-linux-gnu.so | grep RUNPATH

readelf -d /usr/workspace/lei5/myenv/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow/lib.cpython-38-powerpc64le-linux-gnu.so | grep RPATH
```

There is no output for the RUNPATH and the output for the RPATH is

```
[$ORIGIN/../../..:$ORIGIN:/usr/workspace/lei5/myenv/pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyarrow]
```

And I can not update /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 because I don't have sudo access...

In this HPC machine, the newest gcc version is 8.3.1, it does not include 9.2.0

Is there any suggestions? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Hi, could you explain how you installed pyarrow and pytorch?

Comment: Sure, for the pytorch, In order to make it suitable for the powerpc64le architecture. I build OpenBLAS and Magma and compile the pytorch from scratch. And for the pyarrow, I checked their website and found they have wheels for the powerpc64le architecture. So I just use conda install pyarrow. But it seems that the dynamic linker can not find the correct path.... That's why I have the issue...

Comment: I think that's your issue. pyarrow and pytorch would need to be compiled with the same tool chain. So you'd need to install pyarrow from source yourself. See this https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html#installing-from-source

Comment: This is quite possible, the toolchain might have been hardcoded inside. Because even if I use os.environ("LD_LIBRARY_PATH") to add the correct ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} directly inside my python script, the dynamic linker will still lead the .so file to the wrong way. Thanks for your help! And I will try to build pyarrow from source to see if it works.